# TypeScript/ES2015: Prefer `const` instead of `let` reduces readability?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, typescript

ES2015 introduced the `let` and `const` keywords, which essentially have the same semantics apart from reassignment. (`const` can be seen as a `final` variable in languages like Java.)

I see the point of switching from `var` to `let`, but many online articles recommend using `const` whenever possible (in some form of manual [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)).

However, I recall in the [question on Java final variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154314/499922), the accepted most popular answer adviced against using `final` local variables because it makes the code more difficult to understand.

This is reflected in reality as a number of code review comments questioned the "over-use" of `const` on local variables.

So does `const` still reduces readability in JavaScript?

Comment: No, it doesn't reduce readability.  In fact, I think it increases readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*sigh*... This is why immutable needs to be the default.  Even the referenced Java answer suggests this.  Note that that answer does *not* recommend removing `final` modifiers, just that the author of that answer wouldn't add them in new code (for local variables) because they "clutter up" the code.

However, there is a difference between JavaScript and Java here.  In Java, `final` is an *additional* modifier on a variable declaration, so you get:

```
final int foo = 3; // versus
int foo = 3;
```

In JavaScript, though, `const` is just an alternate variable declaration, so the situation is:

```
var foo = 3; // (or let nowadays) versus
const foo = 3;
```

I don't think two more characters constitutes "clutter".  If the alternative being suggested is just `foo = 3` then the reviewers are just wrong.

Personally, I would always use `const` when applicable and would suggest it's inclusion in a code review.  But then I'm a Haskeller, so I would be like that.  But also, JavaScript tends to be more pervasively mutable and have a worse debugging story when things do unexpectedly change, that I would say `const` in JavaScript is more valuable than `final` in Java (though it's still valuable there.)

As Ixrec points out, `const` only controls the modifiability of the binding, not the object that is bound.  So it's perfectly legal to write:

```
const foo = { bar: 3 };
foo.bar = 5;
```

This can be used as an argument against using `const` as someone may be surprised when an "unmodifiable" object is modified.  Newer versions of JavaScript do have a mechanism to actually make objects unmodifiable, namely [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).  It makes a good addition to `const` (though only use it on objects that you create, for example, as `Object.freeze({ ... })`).  This combination will communicate and *enforce* your intent.  If used consistently, the times where you *are* mutating things will stick out and clearly signal non-trivial data flow.

Comment: Admittedly JS `const` doesn't prevent you modifying the value, only reassigning the variable, so the question of whether `const` is more valuable than `final` might be closer to a tie. Completely agree otherwise though, +1.

Comment: @Ixrec That's a good point and can be argued as a reason to not use `const` as it may be interpreted as delivering more than it does.  `const foo = ...; foo.bar = 3;` probably has a touch of cognitive dissonance to it.  (Of course, if objects were [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) as a matter of course... Solution to any problem, more immutability.)

Comment: Agreed, for public-facing stuff always do `const foo = Object.freeze({ ... });` so it's truly bulletproof. For internal stuff it's imo still reasonable to use `const` over `var` and omit just the `Object.freeze()`, since mutating a local variable you shouldn't is a much easier thing to do on accident.

Comment: @Ixrec I think we're on exactly the same page. I was going to add a similar suggestion to my previous comment, but I didn't feel like I needed to tell you, so I'll update the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I have been fiddling with JavaScript for the past few weeks, getting into Node.js, React and stuff, and I don't see a single point against using `const` whenever applicable either.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed good practice to declare variables as `const` (or `readonly` or `final`, depending on the language) if possible.

The author of the linked answer also admits that is is *right* to mark variables as `final`, but the author is simply *too lazy* to do it.

Even if the authors opinion about "clutter" was right, then it wouldn't apply to JavaScript or TypeScript, since `const` is *instead* of `let`, not in addition to.